# anonymous inner class not affect outer class member

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

the output is

```
   foo
   foo
```

but I was expecting it to be

```
    foo 
    bar
    foo
```

I do not under stand why the inner class does not work

```
class Test {

    private String foo = "foo";

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(foo);
        new Object() {
            public void bar() {
                foo = "barr"; 
                System.out.println(foo); //not work

            }
        };

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}


    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t=new Test();
        t.method();
      }
   }
```

Comment: You forgot to call the method: `new Object() { ... }.bar();`

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect it to revert to "foo".

Comment: You are written the code for printing the "barr" but it will not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will affect the outer member but code which made change in member variable must execute so your code should be like this:

```
public class Main {

    private String foo = "foo";

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(foo);
        new Object() {
            public void bar() {
                foo = "bar";
                System.out.println(foo);

            }
        }.bar();

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main t = new Main();
        t.method();
    }
}
```

And output :

```
foo
bar
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is actually:

foo

barr

barr

If you correctly invoke the bar() function after creating the anonymous class:

```
class Test {

    private String foo = "foo";

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(foo);
        new Object() {
            public void bar() {
                foo = "barr";
                System.out.println(foo); 
            }
        }.bar();  // Added invocation here

        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no call to the method `bar()` of the anonymous Object class. That is why the print statement inside it is never executed.
You can update the code as below :

```
new Object() {
            public void bar() {
                foo = "barr"; 
                System.out.println(foo); //not work

            }
        }.bar();
```

to call the `bar` method.
Now that you have executed this method where you assigned the instance variable  `foo` to value `"barr"` , the last print statement in the method() will print the updated value `"barr"`.